# DataAccess Plugin in NopCommerce 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I am trying to create a plugin with data access based on this [tutorial](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/75/plugin-with-data-access.aspx).

When the `Install` method is called it in turn calls `CreateDatabaseInstallationScript`. The scripts generated by the plugin in tutorial generate only the `SQL` for custom tables.

But when function is called in my plugin, it generates `SQL` for about 30 tables.

Following is the `DbContext` class:

```
public class MyProductObjectContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
public MyProductObjectContext(string connectionString)
    : base(connectionString){}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RewardPointsHistory>()
                  .HasRequired(p => p.UsedWithOrder).WithOptional();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyProductMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyProductNoteMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public string CreateDatabaseInstallationScript()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext
                                   .CreateDatabaseScript();
    }

    public void Install()
    {
        //It's required to set initializer to null (for SQL Server Compact).
        //otherwise, you'll get something like "The model backing the 'your 
        //context name' context has changed since the database was created. 
        //Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database"

        Database.SetInitializer<MyProductObjectContext>(null);
        var scripts = CreateDatabaseInstallationScript();
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(scripts);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Uninstall()
    {
        var dbScript = 
@"DROP TABLE LTMyProduct
GO
DROP TABLE LTMyProductNote
GO
";
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbScript);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

None of my Entities refer to any of `Nop.Core.Domain` entities. The entities code is as follows:

```
public class MyProduct : BaseEntity
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    //public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int NotesCount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MyProductNote> Items { get; set; }

    public MyProduct()
    {
        Items = new HashSet<MyProductNote>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyProductNote : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public int MyProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual MyProduct MyProduct { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + 
                         (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MiddleName) ? "" : 
                   (" " + MiddleName)) + " " + LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping (`EntityTypeConfiguration`) for both the classes is as below:

```
public class MyProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyProduct>
{
    public MyProductMap()
    {
        ToTable("LTMyProduct");

        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.CustomerId).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ProductId).IsRequired();

        Property(x => x.ProductName).IsUnicode()
            .IsVariableLength().HasMaxLength(250).IsOptional();

        HasMany(x => x.Items);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyProductNoteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyProductNote>
{
    public MyProductNoteMap()
    {
        ToTable("LTMyProductNote");

        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired()
                  .IsUnicode().IsVariableLength();
        Property(x => x.MiddleName).HasMaxLength(50).IsUnicode()
                  .IsVariableLength();
        Property(x => x.LastName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired().IsUnicode()
                   .IsVariableLength();
        Property(x => x.Note).IsVariableLength().HasMaxLength(1024)
                   .IsUnicode();
        Property(x => x.MyProductId).IsRequired().HasColumnType("int");
    }
}
```

**I have also posted the question on** **[NopCommerce forum](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/25661/getting-error-when-calling-uninstall-method-v31.aspx)**.

Comment: When i added this line,
modelBuilder.Entity() .HasRequired(p => p.UsedWithOrder).WithOptional();


 i am going into another error.....
There is already an object named 'Address_Country' in the database. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line on your OnModelCreating method

modelBuilder.Entity()
                  .HasRequired(p => p.UsedWithOrder).WithOptional();

This line is refrencig the Core data model

Comment: Please have a look here: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/13958/extending-nop-data-model.aspx?p=2#80722 without this line it give another error as specified in the question.